# How to save the navigation action when the condition is true in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, navigation

I have the following verification page called Checkroute and it has the following function that checks if the entered text is equal to the stored text, I used [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store the text if it is true, but I want a way to not repeat going to this page if the previous condition is true - meaning when the application is closed and reopened, the application goes Directly to the home screen page without going to the check page

My Code:

```
class check extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _checkState createState() => _checkState();
}

class _checkState extends State<check> {

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final verifierController = TextEditingController();
  String storedvalue = '25dec2021';
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future init() async {
    final realcode = await UserSecureStorage.getCodestored() ?? '';

    setState(() {
      this.verifierController.text = realcode;
    });
  }

  Codecheck() async {
    await UserSecureStorage.setUsername(verifierController.text);

    if (storedvalue == verifierController.text) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homeScreen');
    }
    else  {
    
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/check');
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Center(
              child: Stack(
            children: [
         
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      .......
                      controller: verifierController,
                    
                    )),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0.38),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                     .........
                        onPressed: () async {
                
                            Codecheck();
                          },
                       ..........
```

Comment: Check for the value in the root widget (MaterialApp) and accordingly set your home widget there.

Comment: @DarShan don't understand , give me some code  !